# Visualize mean NDVI for the past 4 years Jan to Dec to distinguish cropland in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat-8, mosaic, land-use

My goal is to perform supervised classification in a large area using Landsat 8 images. Since the area has a lot of vegetation, it is challenging to accurately distinguish agricultural areas. To make it easier to identify croplands, I plan to visualize the NDVI for each month, enabling me to observe the agricultural seasons. I aim to calculate the mean NDVI for each month over the past four years and make a composite. I intend to create 12 bands, where NDVI1 represents the mean NDVI in January and NDVI12 represents the mean NDVI in December. How can I produce this type of code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R to produce this, I would create a training dataset as a shapefile. In this training dataset, draw polygons in a GIS specifically of both croplands and of the other vegetated areas. Do 20-30 polygons of each class as well as some other classes such as water, impervious, dirt, etc. Import the dataset into your code and then use the formula NDVI = (Band 5 – Band 4) / (Band 5 + Band 4) and add a column into the training dataset with the NDVI value.

this will look something like this:

```
training_data <- working.directory("training_dataset.shp")
training_data <- rasterize(training_data)
###now your training data is corresponds to the pixels

# Set the random number generator
set.seed(99)
# Sampling random 
samp_data <- sampleStratified(training_data, size = 200, na.rm = TRUE, sp = TRUE)
samp_data <- data.frame(samp_data)

col(samp_data)
#this ideally will give you a table with class name you assigned in GIS and a numeric value for each band in the image

NDVI = (image.Band 5 – image.Band 4) / (image.Band 5 + image.Band 4)
samp_data <- add.column(NDVI)
```

This will give you all the columns of class name, individual band values, and a NDVI column.

Comment: The Question is tagged with `google-earth-engine`. Granted, the OP didn't include that in the Question body, nor provide a code sample, but that's grounds for *not* answering it, not for choosing a different tool.